# Unable to install dotnet45 with winetricks on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have wine 8.0.2 in my system and I have installed winetricks a while ago but after running winetricks -q dotnet45 in terminal i am seeing this.

```
Executing mkdir -p /home/ubuntu
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX.
Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. 
If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20210206 - sha256sum: 0f21da98811e0bfda16a7d6d6b8e860a9cedbd4e836c7dd9b02f068d3092ee2e with wine-8.0.2 and WINEARCH=win64Executing w_do_call 
dotnet45Executing mkdir -p /home/ubuntu
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing load_dotnet45
 ------------------------------------------------------
warning: This package (dotnet45) is broken in wine-8.0.2. Broken since 5.18. See https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49897 for more info. 
Use --force to try anyway.
------------------------------------------------------
```

I know that it is crashing and I cannot find solution anywhere to handle this

Comment: This message suggests there is no solution: *Warning: This package (dotnet45) is broken in wine-8.0.2. Broken since 5.18. See https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49897 for more info. 
Use --force to try anyway.*

Comment: like:  winetricks -q dotnet45 --force ??

Comment: I tried t do force it earlier but it did'nt helped me